# Sections of a torsion sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, coherent-sheaves, projective-schemes

I am trying to get a better understanding of torsion sheaves over projective schemes.

Is it true that if $\mathcal{F}$ is torsion over a projective scheme $X$, then $$\Gamma(X,\mathcal{F}) \cong \bigoplus_{p\in X} \mathcal{F}_p?$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. For instance, let $X = \mathbb{P}^2$, let $i \colon \mathbb{P}^1 \to \mathbb{P}^2$ be the embedding of a line, and let
$$
F = i_*\mathcal{O}(-1).
$$
Then $F$ is a nonzero torsion sheaf, but $\Gamma(X,F) = 0$.

EDIT. However, if $X$ is a curve, the result is true. Indeed, the question reduces to the case where the support of $F$ is connected, and if $X$ is a curve, this means that $F$ is supported at a point $p$. Finally, in this case the isomorphism
$$
\Gamma(X,F) = F_p
$$
is obvious --- just note that both sides (as functors from the category of modules over the local ring of $X$ at $p$ to the category of vector spaces) are just the forgetful functors.

Comment: Do things change if I assume $X$ is a curve?

Comment: This depends on what do you mean by $F_p$.

Comment: The stalk of $F$ at the point $p$.

Comment: Then this is true for any coherent torsion sheaf (and the projectivity assumption is irrelevant).

Comment: Could you give me a hint as to why it is true in this case?

Comment: I added an explanation to the answer.

Comment: What do you mean by $\Gamma(X,F)$ and $F_p$ being functors?

Comment: They are functors of $F$.

Comment: So $\Gamma(X,-)$ and $-_p$ are the functors you are referring to?

Comment: This is indeed what I mean.